# Why all materials are not quantum materials, eventhough all materials work under principles of quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, material-science

Quantum materials are now an emerging field of study. I didn't actually understand the need for classifying materials as quantum materials and normal materials. Wave functions of electrons and their spins etc. in normal materials work under the principle of quantum mechanics only. Thus what specifically is meant by quantum material?

Comment: Have you started with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum%20materials)?

Comment: Here's another one: https://www.energyfrontier.us/content/what-are-quantum-materials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Classical material: a material that can be described *both* classically and quantum mechanically.
- Quantum material: a material that can *only* be understood quantum mechanically. Case in point: [magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93van_Leeuwen_theorem).